# Creating file download functionality for zip files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been using some code to download various MIME types such as MP3s (see below) but I can't get it working for Zip files.  Here is my code, can anybody tell me where I am going wrong, I have tried both with the commented line and without and both times I get a 'file not found' type error :

```
[Authorize]
    public virtual FileResult DownloadZip(string fileName)
    {
        var downloadPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Downloads/");
        //fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(fileName), "zip");
        var file = Path.Combine(downloadPath, fileName);
        return File(file, "application/zip", fileName);
    }
```

EDIT : It seems like the Zip files are being changed to Rar files because WinRar is installed on the server, is there anything I can do about this apart from uninstalling WinRar?

Comment: I'd start from debugging the method and checking what's inside `fileName` after the commented line (uncomment it first), does it yield the correct path ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that your ZIP file has been changed to RAR file?

Is it because when you download the file WinRar window pops up, because you have assosiated `*.zip` file extension with WinRar?

Have you verified that `Path.Combine(downloadPath, fileName)` is *really* a zip file?